# how to debug YAFFS?

Tags: android, linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, embedded

I would like to turn on any debugging facility available in YAFFS. I'm hoping it will help me debug the issue that is occuring when using Flash memory. 
Are there any configs in the linux kernel that will help me debug YAFFS? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are, according to the documentation:

> Yaffs has a lot of built in tracing to help debug and integrate. The
>   tracing is controlled by yaffs_traceMask bitmask which allows various
>   sets of tracing to be disabled or enabled at runtime.
>
> The trace bits are specified in the yaffs_trace.h file.
>
> The tracing mechanism has also been ‘hijacked’ to provide a control
>   mask for extra verification code when the YAFFS_TRACE_VERIFYxxx trace
>   bits are selected.
>
> The tracing mechanism is readily integrated into the system via
>   printf-like statements. Tracing is all done through macros which allow
>   the strings to be converted into unicode or similar if need be.

It can be manipulated at runtime, via proc or sysfs interface, e.g.:

```
cat +os > /proc/yaffs # Enables YAFFS_TRACE_OS
cat -all+gc > /proc/yaffs # Disables everything then enable YAFFS_TRACE_GC
cat 0xf000 > /proc/yaffs # Set trace mask to specified bitmask.
```

For details see: http://www.yaffs.net/yaffs-tuning-and-configuration#Tracing_mechanism

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any ideas as to which of those flags will give me nand write errors specifically? I intend to build the kernel with that particular flag set in yaffs_fs.c since the write error is seen during phone boot up.

Comment: I think you should play with it a bit. I've just looked at the `yaffs_trace.h` (http://www.aleph1.co.uk/gitweb?p=yaffs2.git;a=blob;f=yaffs_trace.h;h=fd26054d3912be85c704ca877540611d0ae372a3;hb=HEAD) - I'd try with `YAFFS_TRACE_TRACING`, `YAFFS_TRACE_NANDACCESS` and `YAFFS_TRACE_WRITE` first.